# Latex using OverLeaf inserting image inserts only an empty rectangle with its path

Tags: import, error-handling, latex, overleaf

I have tried both including the path before declaring the beginning of the document and when importing the image. Both times I get the same problem. The image appears as a blank rectangle and I get an error saying that the file has not been found and the file is then run as a draft option. **The run option is !NORMAL! not a draft**

Besides, I am on the OS operating system.

`\includegraphics[width=7cm]{/Users/teddy/Pictures/G1.pdf}`

What could be the issue? I am having trouble finding anything regarding this.

Comment: If you are using overleaf, you probably want to specify the image path relative to your project, not some absolute path, which would only work on your computer. Did you upload the images to your overleaf project and if yes where?

Comment: Yup found an issue, it was silly of me to assume that it can access my picture directory without uploading the actual folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to upload the Folder of images to access them. :)

Comment: This still is not guaranteed to solve the issue. Moreover, having a folder of images is totally optional.

Comment: @cazaimi folder/file or whatever. It did solve an issue in my case, hence my question was answered and may be useful for someone. cheers.